# Calculando a média e a média ponderada com For

Tags: python-3.x, data.frame, ciência-de-dados

porque estou tendo o erro 
  File "", line 50
    print ("Este é o valor da soma dos produtos entre as amostras e seus respectivos pesos", PiXi)"
                                                                                                   ^
para calcular a média ponderada com o conjunto de dados inseridos pelo usuário.

Por estar reciclando os índices n e i , posso ter problemas para criar outros cálculos estatísticos como por exemplo Mediana e Média quadrática?

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
     # Média

```
#Índice referente ao número da amostra.
n=int(input("Insira o número total de amostras"))
#Índice i que vai percorrer todas as amostras
i=0
#Lista vazia para conter as amostras
Amostras=[]
#For para percorrer todo o contador das médias
for i in range(i,n):        
    #Adiciona o valor da amostra dentro da lista de amostras
    Amostras.append(int(input("Insira o valor das amostras")))
#Escreve a lista de amostras na tela para o usuário
print(Amostras)

#Soma das amostras
Xi = 0
#Total 
N = len(Amostras)
for amostrai in Amostras:
    Xi +=amostrai
print ("Esse é o valor da soma das amostras", Xi)
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras que você possui", N)

print ("Esta é a média", Xi/N)

# Média Ponderada

#Lista com os pesos de cada variável
pi = []
#Lista com os valores de cada variável
xi = []

#Lista com os produtos do peso e da variável associada ao índice i
amostraponderadai = []

for i in range (i,n):
    pi.append(int(input("Insira o peso associado a variável: ",i)))
    xi.append(int(input("Insira a variável associado ao índice:", i)))
    amostraponderadai.append(pi(i)*xi(i))

#Soma das amostras
PiXi = 0
Nponderadai = len(amostraponderadai)

#Total do produto da amostra pelo peso
for pixi in amostraponderadai:
    PiXi += pixi
print ("Este é o valor da soma dos produtos entre as amostras e seus respectivos pesos", PiXi)"
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras para a análise da média ponderada", Nponderadai)           
print ("Esta é a média ponderada do conjunto de dados": PiXi/Nponderadai)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kioolz,

Você tem alguns erros, vamos ver um a um.

Seu primeiro erro está na linha do print:

```
print ("Este é o valor da soma dos produtos entre as amostras e seus respectivos pesos", PiXi)"
```

Você deixou uma aspas duplas no final, basta remover:

```
print ("Este é o valor da soma dos produtos entre as amostras e seus respectivos pesos", PiXi)
```

---

Corrigindo esse print, um outro print vai gerar erro:

```
print ("Esta é a média ponderada do conjunto de dados": PiXi/Nponderadai)
```

Você concatenou o retorno de uma divisão com uma string, tirando que o dois pontos está fora da string, podemos deixar a divisão como segundo parâmetro do print e colocar os dois pontos dentro da string:

```
print ("Esta é a média ponderada do conjunto de dados:", PiXi/Nponderadai)
```

---

Legal, com isso seu código vai executar e vamos passar a ter alguns erros durante a execução, o primeiro deles é no input:

```
pi.append(int(input("Insira o peso associado a variável: ",i)))
xi.append(int(input("Insira a variável associado ao índice:", i)))
```

Você passou a variável i como segundo parâmetro da função input, porém ela recebe apenas um parâmetro, podemos apenas remover o i:

```
pi.append(int(input("Insira o peso associado a variável: ")))
xi.append(int(input("Insira a variável associado ao índice:")))
```

---

Após corrigir o input, você terá o erro de acesso a lista:

```
amostraponderadai.append(pi(i)*xi(i))
```

Você tentou acessar as listas pi e xi com parenteses, porém para isso usamos colchetes, vamos substituir:

```
amostraponderadai.append(pi[i]*xi[i])
```

---

Por fim, após corrigir o acesso a lista, seu range vai passar a gerar exceção, pois você utilizou a variável i no range:

```
for i in range (i,n):
```

Podemos remover o i do range, pois você está apenas fazendo um for simples:

```
for i in range(n):
```

---

Após todas essas correções, seu código será executado corretamente, o mesmo ficará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#Índice referente ao número da amostra.
n=int(input("Insira o número total de amostras: "))

#Lista vazia para conter as amostras
Amostras=[]
#For para percorrer todo o contador das médias
for i in range(n):        
    #Adiciona o valor da amostra dentro da lista de amostras
    Amostras.append(int(input("Insira o valor das amostras: ")))
#Escreve a lista de amostras na tela para o usuário
print(Amostras)

#Soma das amostras
Xi = 0
#Total 
N = len(Amostras)

for amostrai in Amostras:
    Xi +=amostrai

print ("Esse é o valor da soma das amostras: ", Xi)
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras que você possui: ", N)
print ("Esta é a média: ", Xi/N)

# Média Ponderada

#Lista com os pesos de cada variável
pi = []
#Lista com os valores de cada variável
xi = []

#Lista com os produtos do peso e da variável associada ao índice i
amostraponderadai = []

for i in range(n):
    pi.append(int(input("Insira o peso associado a variável: ")))
    xi.append(int(input("Insira a variável associado ao índice: ")))
    amostraponderadai.append(pi[i]*xi[i])

#Soma das amostras
PiXi = 0
Nponderadai = len(amostraponderadai)

#Total do produto da amostra pelo peso
for pixi in amostraponderadai:
    PiXi += pixi

print ("Este é o valor da soma dos produtos entre as amostras e seus respectivos pesos: ", PiXi)
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras para a análise da média ponderada: ", Nponderadai)           
print ("Esta é a média ponderada do conjunto de dados: ", PiXi/Nponderadai)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/DelectableSatisfiedSpreadsheets

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado! Eu não havia enxergado tantos erros nas minhas prints e obrigado pelas dicas com o For e com a Síntaxe das listas, isso me confunde um pouco na hora de eu reciclar os índices (i e n) pois eu sempre penso que alguma coisa vai acabar alterando eles e isso pode gerar algum erro numérico no processo seguinte.

Comment: A ideia para este código é acrescentar ainda algumas outras variáveis estatísticas, como por exemplo média quadrática, mediana e moda. 

Alguns parâmetros de dispersão e posteriormente alguns gráficos, 

Ele é um pequeno manual estatístico que tenho de um laboratório de física e que tem técnicas muito interessantes , estou tentando automatizá-lo com o Python como exercício. :)